# PHPMailer SMTP connect() failed. How to resolve?

Tags: php, codeigniter, phpmailer

Codeigniter Config:

```
$config['useragent']        = 'PHPMailer';              // Mail engine switcher: 'CodeIgniter' or 'PHPMailer'
$config['protocol']         = 'smtp';                   // 'mail', 'sendmail', or 'smtp'
$config['mailpath']         = '/usr/sbin/sendmail';
$config['smtp_host']        = 'smtp.gmail.com';
$config['smtp_user']        = 'shahrushabh1996@gmail.com';
$config['smtp_pass']        = '####';
$config['smtp_port']        = 465;
```

Codeigniter Controller:

```
$this->load->library('email'); 
$this->email->from('shahrushabh1996@gmail.com', 'Webers Infotech');
$this->email->to('shahrushabh1996@gmail.com','Rushabh Shah');
$this->email->subject('Your Subject');
$this->email->message('Your Message'); 
if (!$this->email->send()) {
    show_error($this->email->print_debugger());
}
```

Can anyone please tell me How can I resolve this issue? Why is it not working?

Comment: whats the error?

Comment: sometimes SMTP connection failed if DNS lookups are broken of your server. Have you checked

Comment: @DeepKakkar No I not checked it. How can I check it?

Comment: @FabianBettag SMTP connect() failed

Comment: DNS lookup broken if original DNS server goes down

Comment: So many duplicates here on SO, have you checked them?

Answer (score 0):

You can check with the following code:

```
$this->load->library('email');

$config['protocol'] = 'smtp';
$config['smtp_host'] = 'smtp.app.com'; // if via gmail 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com';
$config['smtp_user'] = 'email@dmail.com';
$config['smtp_pass'] = 'smtp password';
$config['smtp_port'] = port number;
$config['starttls'] = TRUE;

$this->email->initialize($config);

$this->email->from('youremail@domain.com');
$this->email->to('to@domain.com');
$this->email->subject('testing');
$this->email->message('Message content');

if($this->email->send()) {
    echo 'Message has been sent';
} else {
    $this->email->print_debugger();
}
```

Also check the `php_smtp.dll` . Is that available or not.

To check that you can use

```
<?php
phpinfo();
?>
```

If not found then check on `php.ini` file and there should be a line as

```
;extension=php_extname.dll
```

just remove the ; from this line and restart php service ( restart Apache ).

Comment: afaik there is no such thing as `php_smtp.dll`